# Why does a rotation about the $z$-axis fix the vector $e_3 = (0,0,1)$

Tags: geometry, vectors

In studying the derivation for the general formula of a rotation about a directed line in $\Bbb R^3$, I came across an example of the reflection about the z-axis, and I have a rather simple question. Why does a rotation about the $z$ axis fix the vector $e_3 = (0,0,1)$ ? This is stated without explanation and it seems semi-intuitive but any further insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: $e_3$ is in the direction along the axis of rotation.  Every vector in this direction will be left alone.  Mathematically, it is because in the standard basis at least, if you write out the matrix that corresponds to a rotation around the z-axis, call it $R_z,$ it is $$R_z = \begin{pmatrix} c & -s & 0 \\ s & c & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ where $c = \cos{x}$ and $s = \sin{x}.$  Its like the identity in the z direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $e_3 = (0,0,1)$ forms a basis for the $z$-axis. Rotating about the $z$-axis is akin to rotating about the span of this vector so clearly it is held fixed. You can think about this visually as looking from above on the $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane. Objects in the plane get rotated as you rotate about the $z$-axis but the single point at the origin, which is projection of $e_3$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$ remains unchanged.